# Trie c++ implementation segmentation fault

Tags: c++, data-structures, trie

I'm implementing a simple trie data structure in c++ using struct and pointers. When I pass a string to add in trie, it gives segmentation fault in the addString() function.

```
struct node {
    char ch;
    node *link[26];

    node() : link(){}
};

node head;


void addString(node *n, string s) {
    if (!s.length()) return;

    if (!n -> link[(int)s[0] - 97]) {
        node m;
        m.ch = s[0];
        n -> link[(int)s[0] - 97] = &m;
    }
    addString(n -> link[(int)s[0] - 97], s.substr(1));
}

int main(){
    addString(&head, "red");
    return 0;
}
```

I tried debug statements and even printed and matched the address values of newly created node and the one passed recursively, they were same.

PS I'm using head node as epsilon state.

Comment: Please don't use the [tag:c] tag in a [tag:c++] question. They're two different tags for a reason.

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: Recommend against the 97. 'a' is almost infinitely easier to interpret.

Comment: πάντα ῥεῖ is correct. An d i tried with clang,gcc,visual studio.... none of them are complaining

Comment: A tip in the same vein as what has already been said: "Debug statements" are the last resort of someone without a better choice. I assure you, you have better choices.

Answer (score 2):

You are using addresses of objects allocated on stack. `node m;` is on stack. It will be deleted as soon as you leave an `if` block in which it is declared. And you assign it's address to a node `n -> link[(int)s[0] - 97] = &m;` which lives longer than that.

Answer (score 1):

```
n -> link[(int)s[0] - 97] = &m;
```

You're storing the address of `m` while it is destroyed at the end of its scope.

You should redesign your project with a proper memory management.

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems that could explain segmentation fault:

- the first is that you add a pointer to a local object `m` into your array of links.  As soon as you return from the function the pointer will be dangling and you'll have UB. Allocate m properly:  `node *m = new node;`  Better: use `unique_ptr` instead of raw pointers.
- you assume that the string contains only lower case letters between 'a' and 'z'.  If the string would contain anything else, you'll go out of bounds  and might cause memory corruption and UB. You should have at least an `assert()`

Here a small fix to address both issues, based on your current structure and approach:

```
struct node {
    ...
    node(char c=0) : link(), ch(c) {} 
    ~node() { for (int i=0;i<26; i++) delete link[i]; }
};
...
void addString(node *n, string s) {
    if (!s.length()) return;
    size_t c = tolower(s[0]); 
    if (c<'a' || c>'z') return;  // char not ok-> do like end of string
    if (!n -> link[c-'a']) {
        n -> link[c-'a'] = new node(c); 
    }
    addString(n -> link[c-'a'], s.substr(1));
}
```

Note that when you use pointers in a struct, you have to be extra-careful about the [rule of 3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming)).  It will not hurt here, though, as you do'nt copy nodes yet.

[Online demo](http://ideone.com/UFTTgI)